# Java multithreading: setPriority()

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading online about **Thread**'s **setPriority()** and came across the following:

```
final void setPriority(int level)
```

> Here, level specifies the new priority setting for the calling thread.

Source:http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=302

What I don't understand is how **setPriority()** alters the priority for the calling thread: shouldn't it affect the object on which it is invoked, the callee? So if I call the method from **main()**, then **main()**'s priority will be altered? This sure looks to me as counter-intuitive.. .

That is unless I don't understand what's meant by a *calling thread*.. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methid `setPriority` is defined in `Thread.java` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority(int)

Priority is helpful hint for thread scheduler to decide which thread to give priority while allocating CPU. By default Main thread starts the execution of a java program. Developers can create their custom Thread.java's objects. When these threads are started then the code initiated by the `run` method of the thread  executes in its path of execution of that particular thread. Each thread is backed by a method call stack. The default priority of the Main thread is 5. Any thread created is provided with the priority value same as of the thread in whose execution path it is created.

You need an object on which you can invoke (call) a method upon.

What do you mean when you say  "...if I call the method from main(),..." ? You just cant call it without any instance of thread. You can create an instance of a Thread and then invoke the method `setPriority` on it. Doing this will set the priority of the thread upon which you invoke the method.

```
Thread usedDefinedThreadReference = new Thread();
usedDefinedThreadReference.setPriority(2);
```

Above will create an instance of the thread and set its priority equal to the currently executing thread , if its main thread then by default its priority is set to 5.

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(6);
```

Above will set the priority of the currently executing thread as 6.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     Thread.currentThread().setPriority(7); // currently executing thread is Main thread and its priority is set as 7 from its default value of 5
     Thread t = new MyThread(); // its priority is set to 7 as current executing thread has priority equal to 7.

    t.setPriority(3); // priority of Thread object referenced by t is set to 3.

   Thread.currentThread().setPriority(8); // main thread is currently executing thread hence its priority is set as 8.

}

public class MyThread extends Thread {

     public Thread(){
          Thread.currentathread().setPriority(9); // Main thread is currently executing thread hence its priority is set as 9.
          this.setPriority(8); // this refers to object of MyThread , the current object hence its priority is set as 8 not of main.
     }
     public void run(){
         Thread.currentThread().setPriority(2); // currently executing thread is MyThread`s object hence its priority is set as 2.
         this.setPriority(4); // again currently executing thread is Object of MyThread hence its priority is set as 4.
     }
}
```

Comment: I mean that if inside main() I instantiate a Thread object and then call setPriority() on that object, which priority will be altered, that of the Thread I created, or main()'s?

Comment: The priority is an integer value which is set when `setPriority` is invoked on the object of the Thread. Its an instance method so it affect the object on which it is called. I have edited my answer for you.

Comment: Thx. So, as I commented above what I read on that webpage seems wrong after all.. .

Comment: The article is good but seams words 'calling thread' made it little confusing, any ways blogs and articles should be referred to but the content must be validated by referring to Java docs and if possible see by implementing and debugging yourself. Blogs and articles may not be reviewed for mistakes which may be unintentional.

Comment: I really tried it all and it was clear and asserted my understanding.. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something there!

Comment: that is good, hope my answer helped you. I would like to add the points as mentioned by GhostCat in his answer. Priority is just a hint, it does not gurantee you much. Better do not code based on value of priority of the threads.

Answer (score 4):

Every piece of code in Java is executed from an instance of a `Thread`.

If you do not write your own threads everything will be executed by a `java-main-thread`.

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some designated class). (from the Java API for [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html))

However you can use multiple `Thread`s across your project to make usage of multi-threading and parallelism technology on your machine.

The method `setPriority` can be used to give the current thread object on which you are calling this method a priority. This priority is used by the thread scheduler of your OS to give the threads CPU time based on their priorities. So a thread with higher priority is more likely to get CPU time than one with a smaller priority.

Again, if you are not using any self made threads you are indeed using a `java-main-thread`. You can always access the current thread you are in by using `Thread.getCurrentThread()`.

So if you have your own Thread class `MyOwnThread extends Thread` and write something like this:

```
MyOwnThread myOwnThread = new MyOwnThread();
myOwnThread.setPriority(...);
```

The priority of the `myOwnThread` is affected. But if you write something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    Thread.getCurrentThread().setPriority(...);
    ...
}
```

You are affecting the `java-main-thread`.

Comment: well explained.

Comment: Hi.. So what I read was wrong then, the priority of the calling thread is not affected by calling setPriority(), it's the priority of the invoking (not the calling) thread that's affected, which may happen to be the same as the calling thread if the current thread is using a reference to itself, as in your example above. Thus, it's basically the invoking thread object (the object on which the method is called) whose priority is adjusted.. . That, or something is still missing here!

Comment: Priority is a field set in the class `Thread.java`.  Think of it like any other class, you invoke the method on an object then its the object on which you invoke the method that gets affected. Its simple `.` operator rule : `referenceOfObjectA.alterState()` will alter state of the object A. if such method is invoked on self from within the class A then it would `referenceOfObjectA` would be replaced by the implicit referwnce `this`.

Comment: Think you have a class `A` and it has a field `int priority` . Now it has a method to set the value `public void setPriority(int priority){ this.priority = priority; }`. Also now suppose there is another method `doSomething(){ this.setPriority(8); A anotherObj = new A(); anotherObj.setPriority(9); }`. What do you think will happen ? Your answer to this question is the answer to the question you have asked.

Comment: Also in case of any doubt its better to see the source code. Its something which beats all other sources.

Answer (score 3):

The really important part here: *priorities* are **only** a recommendation to the underlying operating system.

In other words: the results of using Thread priorities in Java fully depend on things as JVM version, OS type, OS version, ...

Long story short: relying on them is a *waste* of time. Because chances are very close to zero that using this concept will lead to the expected results.

[ personal opinion here: I recently spend hours trying to write priority-based Java threads just to show the effects of priorities - didn't work out; neither for Windows, nor for Linux ]