# Java setPriority() what does it mean?

Tags: java, thread-priority

I'm confused by what `Thread.setPriority` does. Whatever priority I set, it does not matter, it still runs the program name first, then start.

Can someone please explain it to me what happens here?

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        
        Name name = new Name();
        name.setPriority(2);
        
        Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
        welcome.setPriority(7);
        name.start();
        welcome.start();
    }
}

class Welcome extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Welcome!");
    }
}

class Name extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Two threads that each  do a simple operation and stop is not a good example to illustrate thread priority.  You'll only notice the effect in threads that run continuously and concurrently.  The basic idea is if both threads become ready to run at the same time, the higher-priority thread is more likely to be chosen to run than the lower-priority one.

Comment: so in the example above it doesn’t do anything ?

Comment: Essentially, yes , in the case of that example priority has basically no effect (or  none that you'd notice, at least).  Each thread runs for so little time that, for instance,  the `Name` thread, in spite of being the lower-priority thread, might have already started and finished by the time time higher-priority  `Welcome` thread was just getting started.

Comment: There are also no strong guarantees around these priorities. At the most you can use them to achieve some shaping of overall resource usage. If you have a business logic requirement that A has to happen before B, you have to express that with synchronisation mechanisms in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.setPriority` does not set the execution order of threads, but helps the **thread scheduler** to decide which thread should be given priority when **allocating** the CPU.

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44618037/15014077) explains it quite nicely:

> The method setPriority can be used to give the current thread object on which you are calling this method a priority. This priority is used by the thread scheduler of your OS to give the threads CPU time based on their priorities. So a thread with higher priority is more likely to get CPU time than one with a smaller priority.

Answer (score 0):

The setPriority() is only effective within a ThreadGroup. Two scenarios:

- If the set priority is higher than the current max priority of the group the thread is set to the current max security of the group (Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
- otherwise the setting priority is taken

and set by native method

```
private native void setPriority0(int newPriority);
```