# setPriority() method and interrupt() method is not executing

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, interrupt, thread-priority

In the code below I am trying to implement *synchronization*. The code works perfectly fine. But when I try to use the **setPriority()** method or **interrupt()** method it does not give me the desired output. Can anyone let me know what is going wrong here?

*Code:*

```
class Show{
    
    public synchronized void assignjob(String jobname) {
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            
            System.out.println("Your new job role is:"+jobname);
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
            }
        }
        
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread{
    
    Show s;
    String jobname;
    
    MyThread(Show s, String jobname)
    {
        this.s=s;
        this.jobname=jobname;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        s.assignjob(jobname);
    }
}

public class SynchronizationExamples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Show s=new Show();
        MyThread t1= new MyThread(s,"junior developer");
        MyThread t2=new MyThread(s,"Manager");
        MyThread t3= new MyThread(s,"Logistic Officer");
        
        t1.setPriority(4);
        t1.start();
        t3.setPriority(7);
        t3.start();
        t2.interrupt();
        t2.setPriority(6);
        t2.start();

    }

}
```

*Output:*

The output here is not according to the priority set in the code snippet above and neither is the interrupt call handled.

```
Your new job role is:junior developer
Your new job role is:junior developer
Your new job role is:junior developer
Your new job role is:junior developer
Your new job role is:junior developer
Your new job role is:Logistic Officer
Your new job role is:Logistic Officer
Your new job role is:Logistic Officer
Your new job role is:Logistic Officer
Your new job role is:Logistic Officer
Your new job role is:Manager
Your new job role is:Manager
Your new job role is:Manager
Your new job role is:Manager
Your new job role is:Manager
```

Comment: Please explain what output you are expecting, and why.

Comment: @tgdavies I am expecting the output based on the priority I have assigned. That is "Logistic Officer X 5times" then the interrupt call.

Comment: Given that you start thread 1 immediately, I'm not sure why you expect that? And what do you expect that calling `interrupt()` on a `Thread` which hasn't started should do?

Comment: also check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) of `interrupt()`: "*Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.*" ([and](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive()) "*A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.*")

Comment: `jobname` should be `volatile`.

Comment: @PranjalTech What happens if `t1` grabs the lock before any other thread even starts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to understand the meaning of `setPriority`. `Thread.setPriority` does not set the execution order of threads but helps the thread scheduler to decide which thread should be given priority when allocating the CPU.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617921/java-multithreading-setpriority/44618037#44618037) can give you more details.

And regarding the interrupt method, you have it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You are interrupting Thread 2 even before it has started , so It's not going to throw that exception that you are hoping it should .

put that interrupt statement after T2.start()

Comment: Yeah correct. But what about the priority wise output that the thread must execute?